# Excel wrongly translates numeric value from English to Dutch

Tags: excel, csv

I've a input file with some numeric values, when I import this file in Excel (Keeping English as my regional language) the values displayed are as follows :

```
Value in input file : 5214.462
Value in Excel (English) : 5,214.46
```

When I change the language to (Dutch, Belgium) I see the same numeric value as below

```
Value in Excel (Dutch) : 5.214.462,00
```

I read that the '.' in English is represented by ',' in Dutch and vice versa so after translating to Dutch it should be **5.214,46** but it is somehow shown as **5.214.462,00** in Excel

I tried to do the following change :

Go to Excel options > Advanced > Use system separators and change the thousands separator but it won't work.

Kindly let me know if any additional data is needed.
Thanks

Comment: You need to set the region for the csv file import before it gets into Excel. i.e. during the import process.  If you are using the Legacy import wizard, you set it in Advanced settings in Step 3; if you are using Power Query, you go to Transform, and then select to "change data type according to locale" and set the locale to one of the English locales (assuming the csv file is English).

Comment: I tried to change the "File > Option > Language" it didn't work. Also I've a custom macro for importing the input file so can let me know how to change the local language in macro.

Comment: So far as changing your custom macro, suggest you record a macro doing the import properly, and then incorporate what you see into your custom macro.

Comment: Changing the language at that point has zero (no) effect on either the Legacy import wizard or the Power Query import process.  You need to specify the language in one of those areas directly.

Answer (score 0):

There's a checkbox in

```
File > options > Advanced > Use system separators
```

Initially I tried changing the decimal and thousands separators but then it didn't work and I simply ignored the parent checkbox which says Use system separator.

So if you have it checked then Excel tries to read the values in system language and if you expect it to be same as in English then the whole issue arises.

Uncheck the checkbox and Excel tries to read those values using the separators that you have mentioned.

**Unchecking the Use system separators did the job for me.**